# java EE web application/Nuxeo

Tags: jakarta-ee, nuxeo

I’m trying to create a java EE web application allowing to upload, to consult and search a document or a files from Nuxeo. I searched in Nuxeo docs but i can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create your application as Nuxeo modules, and deploy it in Nuxeo, this will allow you to explore Nuxeo through your application, for more details hit this [link](https://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/How+to+create+an+empty+bundle).